# Actionscript / Flash / AIR app - increase maximum memory usage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

It seems like when running an AIR application on Windows, it doesn't like it when it gets around 1GB of memory usage.  Is there a way to change the settings so the VM or whatever monitors / allocates this permits it to use more (e.g. 2GB or 3GB)?

Answer (score 0):

This may be irrelevant to solving the underlying issue because this may not be due to a limit.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10727843/4811197 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/35387564/4811197